# Why does my new C270 webcam work with "cheese" but makes blank images with fswebcam?

Tags: webcam, fswebcam

I have a brand new Raspberry Pi OS image dated 04/2022 on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2 and today I got a brand new Logitech C270 webcam. Everything I read about this camera says it's plug & play and well supported by the rpi3.

I do not get any errors when I try fswebcam. In fact, it creates an image just fine, time stamps and everything, but the image is blank. There is NO cover on the webcam, and I HAVE tested it on another computer. The pi3 **can** see it as a USB device.

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 046d:0825 Logitech, Inc. Webcam C270
```

```
pi@cam:~ $ fswebcam -d /dev/video0 -r 640x480 /var/www/html/test.jpg
--- Opening /dev/video0...
Trying source module v4l2...
/dev/video0 opened.
No input was specified, using the first.
--- Capturing frame...
Captured frame in 0.00 seconds.
--- Processing captured image...
Writing JPEG image to '/var/www/html/test.jpg'.
pi@cam:~ $
```

Here is what it makes:

[image: output from fswebcam]

I see no errors in /var/log/syslog other than these messages:

```
[ 3249.171945] usb 1-1.4: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using dwc_otg
[ 8201.120347] usb 1-1.4: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using dwc_otg
[ 8592.431147] usb 1-1.4: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using dwc_otg
[ 8736.471539] usb 1-1.4: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using dwc_otg
[ 8749.571578] usb 1-1.4: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using dwc_otg
[ 8931.162310] usb 1-1.4: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using dwc_otg
[ 8950.802305] usb 1-1.4: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using dwc_otg
[ 8959.832334] usb 1-1.4: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using dwc_otg
[ 8971.442369] usb 1-1.4: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using dwc_otg
```

I have read that these may be power related, but the camera works with "Cheese."

If I launch the app called "Cheese" I can see the view from the webcam just fine, which tells me that the camera is functional and the pi3 can see it.

The goal is to point it out the window and have it snap a photo every 60 seconds and that's it. Think old weather cam webpage.

I used raspi-config and enabled legacy camera support and rebooted already with no luck.

Edit: I was curious about the power supply, so I bought the official CanaKit 5v/2500mA one just to be sure. The issue persists. Cam works great with Cheese, but nothing else.

Edit: I have also tried all of the other USB ports on the rpi3. They all work. I have a USB keyboard and mouse that also work on every port. The issue persists even if I unplug them.

What are some other things that I can look at? I am willing to give other software a try. This is going to be a headless rpi3 just pointed out the window. that's it.

Comment: Are you using 64 bit raspian? If so, the problem could be related to the change in low-level camera drivers.  The new ones are not yet supported by a bunch of tools.

Comment: I thought about that as well but I am not using the 64 bit version. It is the default 32 bit version that the Raspberry Pi Imager tool offers.